# Upload Image in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, file-upload, xamarin.forms

Hi I have A App by Xamarin.forms use this sampel 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker
for read image from gallery .

I need to upload this image in server but I can not upload this I need a sampel Api And method for send this to api

Comment: https://ilclubdellesei.blog/2018/02/14/how-to-upload-images-to-an-asp-net-core-rest-service-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly , you should convert the stream to Byte array so that you can upload them .

```
public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
{
  var buffer = new byte[16*1024];
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
      return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

And you could use the plugin **FileUploaderPlugin** to upload the image to service .

```
CrossFileUploader.Current.UploadFileAsync("<URL HERE>", new FileBytesItem("<REQUEST FIELD NAME HERE>","<FILE BYTES HERE>","<FILE NAME HERE>"), new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
               {"<HEADER KEY HERE>" , "<HEADER VALUE HERE>"}
            }
);
```

For more details and usage of the plugin you could check https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin